# ASP.NET Core RequestDelegate multiple fire

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm exploring ASP.NET Core Web Applocation empty template. And I'm little bit confused there: if I run the application created by VS new project wizard with no changes and break point on WriteAsync method I could see that it runs two times.

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
```

Does anybody know if this is normal behaviour or a kind of bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use logging for diagnosing these kind of issues. You can use the `Debug` logger to see the log messages in the debug output window.

Add the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug` to your project.json and do the following in Startup.cs's `Configure` method:

`loggerFactory.AddDebug()`

Regarding why you are seeing 2 times, I guess one of the requests is for the `fav.ico` from the browser.

Comment: Looks like you are right. 
According to the Debug logs I could see we've got two GET request for every page update and second requst is favicon.ico request.